# Combining 2 excel sheets with 2 common columns

Tags: excel, vba

Sheet1:

```
col1     col2     
alice     5    
john      7    
sivas     10
```

Sheet2:

```
col1     col2    
alice    3    
john     21    
clara    12    
eric     1
```

I want to combine in such a way, the final result should look like

```
col1    col2    col3    
alice    5       3    
john     7       21    
sivas    10    
clara            12    
eric              1
```

Comment: Welcome to S.O! Have you tried anything? If so, please, provide the code, take a look to the [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Friendly reminder: StackOverflow is not a "we code for you" service provider. [Introduction to VBA](https://blog.udemy.com/excel-macros-tutorial/)

Answer (score 0):

This can be simply achieved using VLOOKUP spreadsheet function.

Let's say that you want the result in a new sheet, we'll call it sheet3, and let's assume that sheet1 and sheet2 have the same number of records, say 30 (if this assumption is incorrect, there are easy solutions to it).

In A1 of sheet3 you enter "=", click on cell A1 of sheet1 and then press the ENTER key. You then copy the formula to cell B1 or sheet3. You then copy the range A1:B1 down till row 30.

Now, you have in sheet3 a dependent copy of sheet1.

Click on cell C1 of sheet 3 and enter the formula:

```
 =VLOOKUP(SHEET2!$A$1:$B$30,A1,2)
```

This will copy the value of column 2 in sheet 2 for the row where column 1 of sheet2 matches the value of A1 in sheet3.

Finally, copy the formula down till row 30.

That's it.